# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning with Node and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I'm using two local Docker containers, one with a MongoDB build and another with a Node app that should connect to the DB. However, I'm receiving the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
web_1  |     at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server_selection.js:309:9)
web_1  |     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:537:17)
web_1  |     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:481:7)
web_1  | (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

This isn't an error with my code as if I run the Node app outside of a container I can connect to a Mongo instance and everything runs perfectly. When it's in a container I can also see the Node express server is running correctly; I just can't connect to the database.

Docker compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: "mongo:latest"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Database connection:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const uri = 'mongodb://db:27017/storytracker';
const run = async() => {
    await mongoose.connect(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        // useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    console.log('DB Connected...');
}

run().catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Articles I've found relating to this all suggest that it's an issue with 'useUnifiedTopology' on the Mongo connection, but removing this flag or setting it to false doesn't seem to change anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!